# curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer

Tags: curl, telegram-bot

I want to setup telegram bot webhook from CentOS, but receive an error:

```
curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
```

My request:

```sh
curl -F "url=https://12.34.56.78:8443" \
-F "certificate=@/home/mts/mtspredbot/mtspredbot.pem" \
https://api.telegram.org/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/setWebhook
```

Is this problem related to my output connection or with something else?

With using -v option:

```
$ curl -v -F "url=https://12.34.56.78:8443" -F "certificate=@/home/mts/mtspredbot/mtspredbot.pem" https://api.telegram.org/token_here/setWebhook
* About to connect() to api.telegram.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 149.154.167.220...
* Connected to api.telegram.org (149.154.167.220) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)
* TCP connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
```

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLESSLCONNECTERROR - probably SSL certificate related.  Try adding `-v` to your arguments for verbose output.

Comment: Added: "With using -v option:"

Comment: Are you using your "home" device? If you're trying to connect to Telegram from Russia, it might be blocked by your ISP.

Comment: I use Yandex Cloud instance, and local socks proxy ft outcome connections. I don't sure about blocking income connection from telegram.